# Formula for Counting how many occurrences in a month

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to figure out how to make a formula that tells me how many "transfers" in each month.  I haven't found anything that works but what I want it to do is say april had 4 transfers

I am using google sheets for this

Comment: Could you give a sample of data you handle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(Range_Containing_Month_Data)=Month_Number_That_Equals_Month))`

Comment: This is really helpful!  Is there a way to have it count when there is a cell that says transferred and another cell is the date range?  for example b2 says transfered c2 says 3/19

Comment: so it will count 1 for that cell but not b3 that says not transferred

Comment: I think you mean: `=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(C:C)=3)*(B:B="transferred"))`